# How do I pass a property (specifically "theme") to "Components" in a next.js app?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, components, react-props

I have a next.js app and this is the `_app.tsx` file:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { createTheme } from '@arwes/design'
import { ThemeProvider, Global, css } from '@emotion/react'
import { globalStyles, blueOnBlack } from '../shared/styles.js'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const theme = createTheme();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      {globalStyles}
      <div style={blueOnBlack(theme)}>
        Futuristic Sci-Fi UI Web Framework
      </div>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

The problem is that I need to access `theme` in `index.tsx`. So how do I pass this into Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to access the parent's `theme` via emotion's `useTheme()`. I have to actually build the component outside of the render area of the page's exported function. In the `index.tsx` file for example:

```
function SomeText(props: any) {
  const theme = useTheme()
  return <div style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.dark3 }} {...props} />
}


// Now that above function "SomeText" can be accessed as a component in "Home"


const Home: NextPage = () => {
    return (
   ...
    <SomeText className={styles.description}>
      Get started by editing{' '}
      <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.tsx</code>
    </SomeText>
   ...
  )  
}

export default Home
```

And that works because the text above is set to "dark3" color.

Answer (score 0):

In the children components, use:

```
const theme =  useContext(ThemeProvider)
```

Comment: added this to my `index.tsx` file and I got `error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` I imported `import { ThemeProvider } from '@emotion/react'` in `index.tsx` so I must be using it wrong. Do you see the problem? https://imgur.com/a/qH46WxR

Comment: you can add a "console.log(theme)" after "const theme = createTheme();" to see if theme is correctly created.

Comment: It says `error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')` so `theme` isn't being created

Comment: @ChristianOConnor use the hook inside the React component.

Comment: I tried `const theme = useTheme(); console.log(theme);` in `index.tsx` and I got `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')`